How to find different representation of permutation in product of transpositions?
It is known that product of transposition to write is not unique. it can be written in many ways,there is theorem that stats that all representation of product of transposition for a given cycle are either all odd or even ( one represent is odd and other is even is not possible). so my question is how to write other representation other than genral one.
I know one way is to include identity permutation
Let G be permutation that iG=G and i can be written as (a,b)(a,b) ot transposition² for all transposition so that is one way to write but i have seen example where I don't understand how it is done like
(123) = (13)(12) = (34)(14)(34)(12) = (34)(12)(12)(14)(34)(12)

There are many ways to write a permutation as a product of transpositions: For example:
$$(a_1,a_2,a_3....,a_{n-1},a_n)=(a_1,a_2)(a_2,a_3)...(a_{n-1},a_n)$$
It is also a fact that any permutation can be broken down into a product of adjacent transpositions : i.e those of the form $(a,a+1)$: Which is a result which can be proven by induction.
Of course, the order of the numbers in the transpositions are also not unique: $(1,2)=(2,1)$ .
You can also break a permutation into its disjoint cycle composition: And then commute those around and then break those disjoint cycles into transpositions.
You can also recognise that $id=(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)$or $id=(1,2)(3,4)(1,2)(3,4)$, or even $$id=(1,2,3,4,5)^5=((1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5))^5$$ Long story short, there are many ways of doing such a thing.
